# How to fix a large dataframe in R

Tags: r

It should be a simple solution, but I don't have a very deep understanding of how R handles data.

I have a dataframe that is the result of importing two columns from a .xlsx file. I'm trying to use the library `anytime` to convert a unix timestamp to an R friendly date. I had no problem with a previous dataframe, and from what I can see this new one is the same structure.

Here is the `dput` from each dataframe:

```
> dput(head(test3,10))
structure(list(city_name = c(NA, NA, "Northampton", NA, "Parkville", 
"San Jose", "San Jose", NA, "Parkville", "Northampton"), dateline = c(1281496979, 
1313188858, 1313188895, 1313188913, 1313188938, 1313188957, 1313188987, 
1313189030, 1313189067, 1313189204)), row.names = 87:96, class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(user,10))
structure(list(userid = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 3, 5), dateline = c(1281496979, 
1281496979, 1281496990, 1281507443, 1281508294, 1281508362, 1281508399, 
1281508589, 1281508603, 1281508629)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The `user` dataframe is the broken one. When I try to run anytime, I get this error:

> Error in anytime_cpp(x, tz = tz, asUTC = asUTC, useR = useR, oldHeuristic = oldHeuristic) : 
>     Unsupported Type

Through my own troubleshooting, I figured out that when I remove `"tbl_df", 
"tbl",` from `class =` then the user dataframe interacts properly with `anytime`. However, the dataframe is about 900,000 rows long, so I can't solve this with `dput`. How can I fix the structure of my `user` dataframe?

Comment: How you you read in the excel-files? The `readxl`-package, is more than capable in reading in excel-datetimes and convert to a POSIXct-variable... Just set `col_types`  as `"date"` inside the `read_excel()`-function.

Comment: `user <- read_excel("C:/.../user.xlsx")`

Comment: is the date set as a date in excel? then use the correct col_types-argument in your code

Comment: or `as.POSIXct(1281496979, origin = "1970-01-01")`... if indeed 1970-01-01 is the right origin --> `[1] "2010-08-11 05:22:59 CEST"`

Comment: `class(test3) <- "data.frame"` or possibly even just `test3 <- as.data.frame(test3)`?

Comment: @Roland both of those solutions work! Thanks! Though it was the `user` df that was broken, not `test3`